# xPages REST Service Results into Combobox or Typeahead Text Field

Tags: rest, combobox, xpages, typeahead

I've read all the documentation I can find and watched all the videos I can find and don't understand how to do this.  I have set up an xPages REST Service and it works well.  Now I want to place the results of the service into either a combobox or typeahead text field.  Ideally I would like to know how to do it for both types of fields.

I have an application which has a view containing a list of countries, another view containing a list of states, and another containing a list of cities.  I would like the first field to only display the countries field from the list of data it returns in the XPages REST Service.  Then, depending upon which country was selected, I would like the states for that country to be listed in another field for selection, etc.

I can see code for calling the REST Service results from a button, or from a dojo grid, but I cannot find how to call it to populate either of the types of fields identified above.

Where would I call the Service for the field? I had thought it would go in the Data area, but perhaps I've just not found the right syntax to use.

November 6, 2017:

I have been following your suggestion, but am still lost as can be.  Here's what I currently have in my code:

```
x$( "#{id:ApplCountry}" ).select2({
                        placeholder: "select a country",
                        minimumInputLength: 2,
                        allowClear : true,
                        multiple: false,
                        ajax: {
                            dataType: 'text/plain',
                            url: "./Application.xsp/gridData",
                            quietMillis: 250,
                        data: function (params) { 
                            return {  
                                search:'[name=]*'+params.term+'*',       
                                page: params.page
                            };
                        },
                        processResults: function (data, page) {
                            var data = $.map(data, function (obj) {
                            obj.id = obj.id || obj["@entityid"];
                            obj.text = obj.text || obj.name;
                            return obj;
                        });
                        },

            return {results: data};
        }
      }
});
```

I'm using the dataType of 'text/plain' because that was what I understood I should use when gathering data from a domino application. I have tried changing this to json but it makes no difference.

I'm using processResults because I understand this is what should be used in version 4 of select2.

I don't understand the whole use of the hidden field, so I've stayed away from that.

No matter what I do, although my REST service works if I put it directly in the url, I cannot get any data to display in the field.  All I want to display in the field is the country code of the document, which is in the field named "name" (not my choice, it's how it came before I imported the data from MySQL.

I have read documentation and watched videos, but still don't really understand how everything fits together.  That was my problem with the REST service.  If you use it in Dojo, you just put the name of the service in a field on the Dojo element and it's done, so I don't understand why all the additional coding for another type of domino element.  Shouldn't it work the same way?

I should point out that at some points it does display the default message, so it does find the field.  Just doesn't display the country selections.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post it please?

Comment: I would recommend to use a plug-in like Select2. It has a built-in feature to load data from a rest service. Example here: http://bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/select2.xsp

Comment: Mark, I'm trying to use that as you're right that it does sound like a viable alternative.  I'm using select2 version 4 and followed the setup for this from Johnny Oldenburger.  I'm still very lost.  I'm receiving SyntaxError: missing : after property id[Learn More]  Application.xsp:399:16 and this is the line where I return some data.  I'll put the code in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue may be that you are not returning SelectItems to your select2, and that is what it is expecting. When I do something like you are trying, I actually use a bean to generate the selection choices. You may want to try that or I'm putting in the working part of my bean below.

The Utils.getItemValueAsString is a method I use to return either the string value of a field, or if it is not on the document/empty/null an empty string. I took out an if that doesn't relate to this, so there my be a mismatch, but I hope not.

You might be able to jump directly to populating the arrayList,  but as I recall I needed to leverage the LinkedHashMap for something.

You should be able to do the same using SSJS, but since that renders to Java before executing, I find this more efficient.

For label/value pairs:

```
LinkedHashMap lhmap = new LinkedHashMap();

Document doc = null;
            Document tmpDoc = null;
            allObjects.addElement(doc);
            if (dc.getCount() > 0) {
                doc = dc.getFirstDocument();
                while (doc != null) {

                        lhmap.put(Utils.getItemValueAsString(doc, LabelField, true), Utils.getItemValueAsString(doc, ValueField, true));
                    } 

                    tmpDoc = dc.getNextDocument(doc);
                    doc.recycle();
                    doc = tmpDoc;
                }

            }


List<SelectItem> options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        Set set = lhmap.entrySet();
        Iterator hsItr = set.iterator();
        while (hsItr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) hsItr.next();
            // System.out.println("after: " + hStr);
            SelectItem option = new SelectItem();

            option.setLabel(me.getKey() + "");
            option.setValue(me.getValue() + "");
            options.add(option);
        }
        System.out.println("About to return from generating");
        return options;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry Brian - this is getting deeper than I understand.  I just want to grab data from a view in another Domino application and display it in a field. I understood the XPages REST Service was the best way to do that. I don't understand if I can return only the fields I want or have to return the whole amount of data.  Then Mark was helpful enough to suggest Select2, which I know nothing about and I'm trying to figure that out. You are helpful in suggesting your Java code, however I don't know how to use Java (my bad) and I'm getting more and more confused. Isn't there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I didn't develop my own using SSJS since I like Java, but here http://www.dominoguru.com/page.xsp?id=POST-DOMO-AQ3MF5.html Chris Toohey does. In his section on "type" you can see adding different keys and values. I think the problem you are having is that what you are returning is not what Select or Select2 expects to get in as options. As you say above, you can see that the REST service executes,

Comment: but it won't work with the selection. So you need to get SelectItems to the field so it will allow you to select them. But if this data is in a Notes Database,  you don't need a REST service. Take a look at @DBColumn to get the values from a view in your other database, that pumps it through many fewer processes to get you the result you want.

Comment: I can't use @DbColumn because the number of items returned is way beyond the limit.  That's why I'm trying to go with a REST service.  I'll take a look at Chris Toohey's post and see if I can understand more about how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using straight up SSJS.  Worked like a charm - very simple.